# monitoring the number of RDP users using nagios core?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, rdp

I'm using Nagios Core 4.3.4. Is there any way to monitor the number of users connected to the server RDP on a Windows server like nrpe check_users? Please tell me if you have.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to write your own check for this.

In your check you could call a powershell script on the server (but it depends on your windows version):

```
ipmo RemoteDesktop           # 1. import the remotedesktop module
$(Get-RDUserSession).count   # 2. print the count of the session
```

But there is another approach mentioned on [monitoring-portal.org site](https://monitoring-portal.org/woltlab/index.php?thread/25459-anzahl-der-rdp-user-%C3%BCberwachen/). It's in german, so I try to translate:

1.) read window performance counters with nsclient:

```
c:\program files\nsclient\nsclient++.exe -noboot CheckSystem listpdh >counters_list.txt
```

2.) define the command (where `-s $USER7$` is the passphrase to establishe the connection

```
define command{
    command_name    check_nt_Counter_User
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nt -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -s $USER7$ -p 12489 -v COUNTER -l $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$ -d SHOWALL
}
```

3.) define the service

```
define service{
    service_description     RDP-Sessions    
    host_name               TerminalSrv
    use                     sometemplate
    check_command           check_nt_Counter_User!"\\Terminalservices\\active sessions","RDP-User active","users"!18!20
    notes                   get count of active sessions
    process_perf_data       1
    notifications_enabled   0

}
```